# Selenium Web driver saying No class definition found in JSF project

Tags: java, jsf, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium Web driver to capture screen in a JSF project using ANT. I have included all the jar files list is below in the image:

[image]

When I try to deploy it on jboss, it fails saying 
**"Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"**.

The code I'm using is:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:/capture/screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: What imports are used and when were the versions last updated in the project? Also are you trying to deploy the code? Please add the details to the question itself.

Comment: @nullpointer i'm just developing the project, so using the latest versions. Yes it gives me exception when i try to deploy the code on JBOSS.  The imports i'm using are already mentioned in the question in an image.